# How to count matching and non-matching records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, databricks

What are ways to count matching and non-matching records from two different tables in the sever (table `i` and `h`). For example, count matching records if `i.id = h.id` and and count non-matching records if `i.id != h.id`.

The logic makes sense in my head, but I'm struggling to come up with the code. I've tried the `case` statement, but that did not work. I only need the total count for matched records and the total count for un-matched records in table `h`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about exactly what you need, but maybe something like that can help you:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(i.id) AS matching_count,
    COUNT(h.id) - COUNT(i.id) AS non_matching_count
FROM h
    LEFT JOIN i ON h.id = i.id;
```

The above query will tell how many ids exists in both tables and how many ids in the table `h` does not exists in the table `i`.

Or the inverse logic:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(h.id) AS matching_count,
    COUNT(i.id) - COUNT(h.id) AS non_matching_count
FROM i
    LEFT JOIN h ON i.id = h.id;
```

The above query will tell how many ids exists in both tables and how many ids in the table `i` does not exists in the table `h`.

Or maybe you want something like that:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN h.id = i.id THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS matching_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN h.id != i.id THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS non_matching_count
FROM h, i;
```

The above query will tell how many ids exists in both tables and how many divergences exists in the cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to summarize first at the `id` level:

```
select id, max(in_i) as in_i, max(in_h) as in_h
from ((select id, 1 as in_i, 0 as in_h
       from i
      ) union all
      (select id, 0, 1
       from h
      )
     ) ih
group by id;
```

Then summarize this:

```
select count(*) as num_total_ids,
       sum(in_i) as num_i, sum(in_h) as num_h,
       sum(in_i * (1 - in_h)) as in_i_only,
       sum(in_h * (1 - in_i)) as in_h_only,
       sum(in_i * in_h) as num_both,
from (select id, max(in_i) as in_i, max(in_h) as in_h
      from ((select id, 1 as in_i, 0 as in_h
             from i
            ) union all
            (select id, 0, 1
             from h
            )
           ) ih
      group by id
     ) i
```